# Error fetching custom collections: Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Recieved invalid status 403 response

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio, visual-recognition

I am using **IBM Watson** Visual Recognition for a custom model. I have uploaded my dataset as .zip files, which is fine so far. However, I cannot test  already trained model and  I cannot label new images. When I go on my Watson services, it says:

```
Error fetching custom collections: Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Recieved invalid status 403 in getAllCollections response for guid crn:v1:bluemix:public:watson-vision-combined:us-south:a/649b0335a5a44f6d80d1fd6909e466f9:8a71daa3-b0be-42ac-bb72-1473de835c19:: at endpoint https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/
```

When I try to label new images , it says: Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Received empty image data response

To the best of my knowledge, I have checked Google and StackOverflow for solutions, but didn't find any. I am using the Lite version. I only have one project, and one **Visual Recognition** instance. Please note that it worked for a different Visual Recognition model before, but later I could not use or access that model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 is a forbidden error, implying that you don't have authority to access the custom collections. Which is strange as its part of the V4 API available to lite accounts.

If you are doing everything inside Watson Studio, then Watson Studio is accessing the service on your behalf. Watson Studio may have expired its access token. Try flushing your browser cache, logging back into Watson Studio and trying again.

If that doesn't work, you should raise a ticket against Watson Studio.

You can verify if it is a Watson Studio problem by using cURL to list the customised collections - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v4#list-collections

```
curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "{url}/v4/collections?version=2019-02-11"
```

If you still get a 403, then the problem lies with the service. If the cURL command works, then the problem lies with Watson Studio, and how you are using it.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, it is working fine fine, although I can't really tell what I did that made it work, but I think it has something to do with the flushing of browser cache, then logging backing into watson studio...

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider, since you mentioned you were using a lite plan, is that once you have exhausted the monthly quota of resources for this free plan, you will get 403 error codes.